# Rails/ruby Calculate new Coordinates using Given Distance and Bearing from a Start Point

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, geolocation, geometry

Is there a simple, non-math-class and definitive way to do this in ruby/rails where the inputs are:

```
1) An Initial Geo-Coordinate 
2) A Bearing
3) A Distance in the Bearing's Direction
```

And the Output is a new `Geo-Coordinate`

I've had a look at the [Ruby Geocoder Gem](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/), but it doesn't do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First hit for "distance bearing" in Google: [Calculate distance, bearing and more between Latitude/Longitude points](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html#destPoint)

The JavaScript code works just fine in Ruby:

```
lat1 = 0.9250245 # starting point's latitude (in radians)
lon1 = 0.0174532 # starting point's longitude (in radians)
brng = 1.67551   # bearing (in radians)
d    = 124.8     # distance to travel in km
R    = 6371.0    # earth's radius in km

lat2 = Math.asin( Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(d/R) + 
          Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(brng) )
# => 0.9227260710962849                  

lon2 = lon1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(lat1), 
                 Math.cos(d/R)-Math.sin(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2))
# => 0.0497295729068199      

# NB. Ensure that all values are cast to floats
```

Comment: thanks Stephan - i'd already tried that, but hadn't done the conversion to radians. unsurprisingly it work beautifully now!